# Python returns error, but Command Line doesn't

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, subprocess, python-os

I'm trying to use this command to get all running processes

```
wmic /output:C:\\ProcessList.txt process get caption
```

When I run this in cmd it works and outputs everything to the specified file.

When I try running this with Python I get an error saying:

```
Invalid file name.
```

I tried running it with os.system and subprocess.call, but both return an error.

```
os.system('wmic /output:C:\\ProcessList.txt process get caption')
subprocess.call('wmic /output:C:\\ProcessList.txt process get caption')
```

I also tried using raw strings.

```
os.system(r'wmic /output:C:\ProcessList.txt process get caption')
subprocess.call(r'wmic /output:C:\ProcessList.txt process get caption')
```

But nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Carcigenicate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000206/carcigenicate)

helped me reach the answer. The code from his answer gave me the real error. My code was giving me `Invalid file name.` His code returned: `Permission denied: C\\ProcessList.txt`.So it was a permission problem. I just ran my IDE with admin rights and it worked.

To avoid having to run my IDE in administrator mode all the time, I just buried the file into Documents, so I don't need admin privileges to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Python reads a \\ as \, so what you have to do is:

```
os.system('wmic /output:C:\\\\ProcessList.txt process get caption')
```

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue. Still the same error. But I don't think the thing you wrote is correct, because it would feed `C:\\ProcessList.txt` into cmd, but it should feed `C:\ProcessList.txt`

Comment: are you sure that the / before output then shoudlnt be a \  ? I'm pretty sure you're mix of backslashes is the problem here. try: os.system('wmic \\output:C:\\ProcessList.txt process get caption')

Comment: Someone else helped me to get to the answer. The syntax was right, but it was a permission problem. If you're interested, look up into my own answer. I can't mark it as right for 2 more days, so that's why this question is still open.

Answer (score 0):

As you can notice, you are using 2 backslashes in the command prompt. So, in order for the path to work in python you will need 4 backslashes. The reason being that backslash (`\`) is a special character within a string. So, in order to use a single backslash character, you must escape the backslash which is done by putting 2 backslashes back to back like so: `\\`. You can also use raw strings which is nothing but a string prefixed with an "r" (`r'...'`) which automatically escapes all the backslashes.

Thus, you can use one of the following:

- Using raw strings (automatically escapes the backslashes):

  ```
  r'wmic /output:C:\\ProcessList.txt process get caption'
  ```
- Escaping the backslashes manually (4 backslashes):

  ```
  'wmic /output:C:\\\\ProcessList.txt process get caption'
  ```

Comment: Someone else gave me this as the answer and it didn't work. Cmd should get `C:\ProcessList.txt` and not `C:\\ProcessList.txt`